# Travel within the EU with only a Romanian ID card

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, eu-id-card, romanian-citizens

Can I travel within the EU with only a Romanian ID card (I'm a citizen of Romania)?

I will start crossing the EU from the Poland-Ukraine border, then I'll go to Hungary, the Czech Republic, Germany and Austria. I don't have a passport, just an ID card. Will it be easy to cross all thse borders (including the border between Ukraine and Poland) with an ID card only (non-biometric)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Romanians can't enter Ukraine with an ID card; only Ukrainian and Turkish citizens can.

So you have to go to Poland through Hungary and Slovakia.

**EDIT**: as a dual Romanian-Ukrainian citizen, you can use your Romanian ID to enter the Schengen Area (in your case through Poland)

Comment: He could be starting from Ukraine.

Comment: @TomasBy They Need a passport to leave Ukraine as well.

Comment: @coke I've got Ukrainian citizenship, that's alright with Ukraine. I just want to know if I can enter Poland from Ukraine border with only Romanian ID Card. Without any other documents.

Comment: @toptrader Yes, you can use your Romanian ID for that, no problem. You show your Ukrainian passport or ID on the Ukrainian side, then the Romanian ID on the Polish side.